# How to dereference the pointer returned by a function?

Tags: c, pointers, return, pass-by-reference, gcc7

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int *sum_returning_pointer(int *x, int *y)
{
    // Call be reference
    int z = (*x) + (*y);
    return &z;
}

void main(int *argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    int *p = sum_returning_pointer(&a, &b);
    printf("Sum = %d\n", *p);
}
```

With the above function i'm trying to add up the two numbers which are passed as a reference to the called function and returning pointer pointing to the variable where sum is stored. But i'm getting weird error saying.

```
Error has occured.
Segmentation Fault.
```

> What does this error mean?
> How can i achieve a solution ?
> Why does this error occurs ?

Comment: z is a local variable and its scope ends when the function exits. Using it outside the scope invokes UB. The compiler should warn you about that

Comment: You can't access the value of `z` after the function ends (it's undefined behavior).

Comment: I was referring to this vide. https://youtu.be/zuegQmMdy8M?t=10383 where it worked fine. Any clues ??

Comment: It may *happen* to work in some cases, but it's undefined behavior, which means no particular result can be assumed.

Comment: I can't believe that video's top comment says "Best explanation on pointers ever" when it encourages undefined behavior.

Comment: @sbhusal123: One possible outcome of undefined behavior is that code behaves as expected. Another possible outcome is garbled output, corrupted data, or a runtime error.  This example is not only poorly written, it’s also a *horrible* demonstration of why pointers are useful.

Comment: @sbhusal123 stop using online tutorials and youtube for learning. Most of them are very bad. Read a good book instead: [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/995714). Probably because no experts watch such videos, it's still there without any comments pointing out the serious error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In main function z is not accessible that's why it is  showing undefined behavior. You can declare z as a global variable like

```
#include <stdio.h>
int z =0;
int * sum_returning_pointer(int *x, int *y)
{
// Call be reference
z = (*x) + (*y);
 return &z;
 }

  void main(int *argc, char *argv[])
  {

   int a = 1, b = 2;
   int *p = sum_returning_pointer(&a, &b);
   printf("Sum = %d\n", *p);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not how to dereference but how to assure that the pointer is valid. In your code the address of a local variable is returned. This lifetime of this variable ends when program returns from the function. Dereferencing this pointer after that invokes *Undefined Behavior*.

Note, that typically small objects like `int` should be returned by value.

There are 3 generic strategies of returning a pointer to the result from a function.

1. (IMO, the best) Let the caller handle the lifetime.

```
int *foo(const int *x, const int *y, int *z) {
  *z = *x + *y;
  return z;
}
```

Usage:

```
int x = 1, y = 2, z;
int *res = foo(&x, &y, &z);
```

2. Use dynamic storage

```
int *foo(const int *x, const int *y) {
  int *z = malloc(sizeof *z);
  if (!z) {
    // complain
    return NULL;
  }
  *z = *x + *y;
  return z;
}
```

This solution tends to be very slow and error prone because the caller is responsible for freeing result.

3. Use static.

```
int *foo(const int *x, const int *y) {
  static int z;
  z = *x + *y;
  return &z;
}
```

Works well because lifetime of a static variable extends for the whole execution of the program.

The main issue is that the object pointed by the pointer will change with every invocation of `foo`. That is especially dangerous for multi-threaded applications.